# GWT HorizontalPanel setSpacing?

Tags: java, css, gwt, padding

Is there a way to set padding on GWT's `HorizontalPanel`?

I wanted to just have 20px left padding and then add few buttons.
Currently I can only add `setSpacing()` and that puts padding on top, left, right and bottom.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could (and should) use CSS for this, something like:

```
.paddedHorizontalPanel {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

And if you want every `Button` in that `HorizontalPanel` to be `20px` apart, then you can try this instead:

```
.paddedHorizontalPanel .gwt-Button {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

And then add this style to you `HorizontalPanel` via [`hPanel.addStyleName("paddedHorizontalPanel");`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#addStyleName(java.lang.String))
More on CSS and GWT in [the docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html).

PS: AFAIK, not including setPadding was a concious choice on part of the GWT team - they wanted to leave the styling of the application entirely up to CSS.

Comment: Thanks Igor. your suggestion was very helpful.

Comment: No problem :) If this solved your problem, you should mark this as the answer to your question (click the tick next to the answer) - keeps the site clean (you know which questions are answered and which not).

Answer (score 6):

In worst case you can always do :

```
HorizontalPanel p = new HorizontalPanel();
p.getElement().getStyle().setPadding(20, Unit.PX);
```